# Transfered EE site to cPanel and keep getting errors

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, debugging, cpanel

Had this site on an ispManager server. Moved it over to cPanel and kept getting errors. Now down to this. Not sure why I can't get the site to pull up and just how to fix these errors.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for CI_Loader::is_loaded(), called in /home/davidsdrycleaner/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Loader.php on line 74 and defined

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 93

The code from line 93-100 is as follows, which also works for error #2..

```
public function is_loaded($class) { if (isset($this->_ci_classes[$class])) { return $this->_ci_classes[$class]; }

  return FALSE;
```

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: class

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 95

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/davidsdrycleaner/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 443

```
The code on line 443 is... header("Status: {$code} {$text}", TRUE);
```

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/EE_Config.php

Line Number: 208

```
The code on line 208 is $query = ee()->db->get_where('sites', array('site_id' => $site_id));
```

Comment: maybe it's best you re-upload yor files, check the php version and relevant installed php extentions.

Comment: Also worth checking your database details in config.php are correct.

Comment: Here is where I am at, I have the home page pulling up back still have these 2 errors showing...  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Char_limit::usage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: char_limit/pi.char_limit.php

Line Number: 35

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/davidsdrycleaner/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 443